# Working with SwipeRefreshLayout and WebView inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `WebView` in my application with no problems.

Inside the `ViewPager` code:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    currentArticle = newsList.get(position);

    View webViewContainer =  getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, null);

    WebView webview = (WebView) webViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    SetSettingForWebView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl(currentArticle.getArticleURL());
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) webViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    setSettingForSwipeLayout(swipe);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(webViewContainer, 0);

    return webViewContainer;
}
```

The error occurs regardless whether I define the `SwipeRefreshLayout` or not.

This is the error. As you can see it's not related to my code but I don't know how to solved this one

LOG:

```
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665): Process: com.dimrix.test, PID: 4665
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.startRefresh(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:441)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onTouchEvent(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:399)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7811)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2169)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1613)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2539)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2117)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8005)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4300)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4179)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3764)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3733)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3741)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3901)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3764)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3733)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3741)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5973)
05-25 21:55:59.804: E/AndroidRuntime(4665):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.ja
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 441 of `SwipeRefreshLayout.java` is

```
    mListener.onRefresh();
```

Did you [provide an `OnRefreshListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setOnRefreshListener%28android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener%29) for it?

Comment: i did . and i even if i didn't i doesn't suppose to crash .

Answer (score 0):

Go to project->**Properties**->**Java Buildpath** and add supporting **library V4** and check the library from **order and Export** tab by ensuring the tick mark is ticked.

Comment: as i wrote , the swipe works fine at other fragments in my application

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because you have the `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside the ViewPager, i.e. in `view_pager_item.xml`. So when the `SwipeRefreshLayout` looks for its context, it will find the Activity or Fragment that contains the ViewPager.

Try moving the the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to the Activity or Fragment that contains the ViewPager and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set the SwipeRefreshLayout view with a listener ?

For example, if your Fragment/Activity implements `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`, you need to set the SwipeRefreshLayout instance as:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout layout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
layout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

This should fix the crash :)